# Given path to file by user wont work c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a path from the user, then insert it into `ifstream`, but it doesn't work. My file is located at: `C:\test.txt` I used double backslash, but it is still not working.

```
string pot;

cout<<"GIVE PATH TO FILE:"<<endl;
getline(cin,pot);
//pot="C:\\test.txt";
string line;
string besedilo[2];
short i=0;
ifstream myfile (pot.c_str());
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        besedilo[i]=line;
        i=i+1;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Are you using _double backslash_  from the input prompt?

Comment: yes, i tried both, with double and without

Comment: How did you find out that the program doesn't work?

Comment: Array 'besedilo' doesn't fill,

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code... And it worked perfectly for a .txt file on my D: disk.
Just be sure you used **double slash** and properly wrote **path**. I don't see any other option why it's not working like you want.

Comment: From input _double slash_ isn't required.

Comment: may i ask which IDE you use and what exactly you wrote in command line? thank you for testing

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I wrote: 
D:\\sample.txt
And it worked out for me.

Comment: i figured it out, i moved initialization of line,besedilo[2] and i  before getline and it worked, still dont know why... if someone know explanation, iam here :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Boost Filesyetm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html).  It's platform agnostic and handles all those backslash, forward-slash, escape-slash headaches.

Comment: While this is a good advice, does it really answer _"the question"_?